# Python Requests.get() not working with multiprocessing pool.map

Tags: python, python-requests, multiprocessing, screen-scraping

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import requests
import time as time
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36'}
def foo(url):
    print('requesting')
    x = requests.get('http://www.facebook.com', timeout = 10, headers = headers)
    time.sleep(1)
    print('requested')
pool = Pool(6)
try:
    dump = pool.map(foo, range(20))
finally:
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
```

I am trying to scrape websites in parallel using pool.map. The above code is a minimum example. I ran the above code in jupyter notebook and the Requests.get() just hang there.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "just hang there"?

Comment: Try running outside of jupyter. With jupyter there can be concurrency issues requiring tasks to set.

Comment: @NicoHaase not responsive. It's like it's stuck at requesting for the website.

Comment: @QHarr could you elaborate a bit more on how to solve this issue in jupyter?

Comment: Run as a .py outside of jupyter is easiest way and see if problem still persists. I could be wrong so worth checking.

Comment: @QHarr outside of jupyter the problem doesn't occur indeed!